# Stack exchange for programming beginners?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am just learning how to program, and I have been using Stack Exchange.  I think it is a fantastic idea for a website, and I think the moderations helps the community as a whole.

However, for someone new to programming like myself, it is hard to ask and answer questions in a constructive way.  I can only answer a small fraction of the questions, and by the time I've written out the code myself, someone has answered it before me, invariably because the problems are hard for me to solve as well.

This is where a Stack Exchange site geared towards beginners would be beneficial to us who are ignorant of asking dumb questions.

I think Meta stack exchange is geared towards conversation, so, what do you guys think?

Comment: I'd like that, but for different reason, my questions gets down-voted because I don't know a certain 'new' way of doing things. I'll ask something like "How to get from point A to B? and the answer are "take the jet fighter", "don't you know how to flight a jet fighter?", "read about flying jet fighters before posting a question"... All because I forgot to mention I'm currently riding a bikecycle (and had no idea we could use jet fighters...)

Comment: I see how that's related but my question was: should there be a stack exchange for beginners?

Comment: @jonsca I don't think that's a fair close target; while it covers the same content, I think the votes on that question reflect the asker's attitude, not the content of the question.

Comment: There's loads more dupes, pick your poison.

Comment: (that happened to be the one I ran into which was used as a duplicate for more recent requests)

Comment: Yeah, actually, @jonsca, I'll get behind this vote. I would suggest using [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139216/what-do-you-think-of-an-so-for-beginners-only) instead, but it doesn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: @JerryWalker dupes is short for "duplicates" - as in questions that ask the same thing as the one you are asking.  It refers to the question, not the poster.  For example, your question is substantially similar to [What do you think of an SO for beginners, only?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/) which is a dupe (or duplicate) of [Propose Newbie-Overflow site or section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50409/)

Comment: The problem with a "Stack Overflow for beginners" is... that only beginners will use it. You will get no experts and not expert answers.

Comment: Well, a Stack Overflow for beginers might work if there is a way t transfer some rep points to the main SO

Comment: One of the better received proposals is *[Create a separate, independent advanced Stack Overflow, focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)*.